# Make reference to the name of the thing you refer to

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I'm giving an example

```
\section{About Cats and Dogs}\label{sec:catsdogs}
some text
[...]

In Section \ref{sec:catsdogs}, we have ...
```

I know there's a command `\nameref{sec:catsdogs}`, but this just gives me the `About Cats and Dogs`.

Now I want to have a command that gives me the `Section` instead, like this:

```
In \some_new_command{sec:catsdogs} \ref{sec:catsdogs}, we have ...
```

yielding:

> In Section 1.1, we have ...

Does this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the package `cleveref` for this.

The command `\namecref{sec:catsdogs}` does exactly what you want.

Anyway you might want to try `\cref{sec:catsdogs}` instead of `\namecref{sec:catsdogs} \ref{sec:catsdogs}`, which does it automatically.

MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{About Cats and Dogs}\label{sec:catsdogs} some text [...]

In \namecref{sec:catsdogs} \ref{sec:catsdogs}, we have ...

In \cref{sec:catsdogs}, we have ...

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The variants `\nameCref` and `\Cref` print the name with the first letter uppercased.